# Object Inheritance, Sealed Method Overrides, and C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I've got an abstract class defined by another assembly (not editable):

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Go("Hello World");
    }

    protected virtual void Go(string message)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Now I have a library that I want to inherit from this class which implements Go().  The trick here is that I don't want anyone inheriting from me to be able to override my implementation of Go(), but I also don't want to change the signature in any way.  I actually want both implementations to be called.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
public abstract class B_Intercept : A
{
    protected sealed override void Go(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Go_Impl(message);
    }

    internal abstract void Go_Impl(string message);
}

public abstract class B : B_Intercept
{
    protected new virtual void Go(string message)
    {
    }

    internal override void Go_Impl(string message)
    {
        Go(message);
    }
}
```

Now my end users can switch their class' inheritance from A to B with no effect (other than my Console.WriteLine).

```
public class C : A // This can be changed to B with no other edits
{
    protected override Go(string message)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, the original library can be given an instance of C, it'll be boxed as an A, and the original library will call Run().  Run will use B_Intercept's Go(), which will dump the message to console, then call Go_Impl().  Go_Impl will be run in B, which will call B's Go() which can be override by C.

This feels really circuitous.

There's an added benefit of some security around the methods (they can't call Go_Impl directly), but there are still holes (they can call base.Go).  I think those holes can be closed up with a third layer, but I haven't tried it and frankly I think that's a bit ridiculous.  But it still feels like a lot of boilerplate code.  There's also the lame side effect of B_Intercept needing to be public instead of internal, which raises the surface area of my library in an unexplained way.

Is there a simpler, more secure way?

Comment: I am a bit confused by this question. I would ask two clarifying questions. (1) how does the "sealed" method modifier not do exactly what you want?  Why are you jumping through all these hoops when you could simply override Go and seal it?  and (2) what do you mean "they can still call base.Go" -- who can still call base.Go, and if they do, why do you think it will call A.Go?  Surely the base of a class overriding B is B, not A. Can you clarify?

Comment: Ultimately what I'm trying to do is build a library with a class that nestles between A and C.  Right now they've got class C derived from class A.  I want them to derive from B which derives from A, without having to change their override signatures.  I hope that answers (1).  As for (2), you're right, but I would prefer it if class C couldn't call base.Go(), as this sets them up for unexpected behavior at best.

Comment: One of the fundamental ideas of OO programming is that *the dev writing the derived class knows more about the problem domain than the dev writing the base class*. The dev writing Newspaper knows more about newspapers than the dev who wrote Publication, who knows more than the dev who wrote Object. And furthermore, since the consumer of the base class is the one who *chooses* to re-use the functionality of the base class, presumably they know what it is and how to use it safely. It sounds to me like you have more of a user education problem and less of a technical problem.

Comment: In other words: don't spend too much effort trying to prevent the derived class author from shooting themselves in the foot. Rather, provide them with a compelling, useful base class and teach them how to use it effectively, and then trust them to do so.

Comment: @Eric He essentially wants `"public override sealed Method()"` that is a method that overrides a base implementation but cannot be further overridden in derived classes. I wanted something like that a couple of times (cf the email i sent a couple of days ago regarding private inheritance - thanks for your answer by the way!)

Comment: Actually I think the best way to describe what I'm looking for is "public override sealed Method()" with "public new virtual Method()" in the same class (with the same signature).  Or at least a pattern for accomplishing the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to do something which was not the intention of the developer of the original class.

`Go` has been provided as a `virtual` method and now you are trying to *hide* it while you want to keep it as OO as possible - (**UPDATE**) and not just that, you are also concerned about inherited classes calling base method. I earnestly congratulate you on your effort, care and attention but **something has got to give**.

*Either* you must use `composition` to wrap an A class and provide only the interfaces you intend to provide and fit your design *or* you have to use `inheritance` and accept its short-coming which mainly are arisen from the fact you are really changing the intended behaviour of the class. **For my two cents, I would go with the first option: `composition`.** At the end of the day, this is really what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks  @Eric. You are absolutely right, nothing special about sealing a virtual method. But he is concerned about inherited classes to call the base method. That cannot be prevented without using `new`.

Comment: I understand I'm trying to stretch the definition of OO, I'm just trying to determine how elastic that definition is.  If this is not a solid approach, then I'll rethink the design.  I'm certainly not married to this approach, but for the moment this is the path I'm exploring.

Comment: The more I read this question the less I understand what the OP wants.